# How to add an element to an existing xml file at specific locations using python?

Tags: python-docx, xml.etree

part of word document xml:

```
    <w:p w14:paraId="1A403538" w14:textId="03591853" w:rsidR="00280630" w:rsidRDefault="00280630" w:rsidP="00280630">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>
            <w:t>Chapter to Hide</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

I would like to add a `<w:vanish/>` element programmatically where it is seen below:

```
    <w:p w14:paraId="1A403538" w14:textId="03591853" w:rsidR="00280630" w:rsidRPr="000E4C6C" w:rsidRDefault="00280630" w:rsidP="00280630">
        <w:pPr>
            <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
            <w:rPr>
                <w:vanish/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r w:rsidRPr="000E4C6C">
            <w:rPr>
                <w:vanish/>
                <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
            </w:rPr>
            <w:lastRenderedPageBreak/>
            <w:t>Chapter to Hide</w:t>
        </w:r>
    </w:p>
```

What I want to do would be something like this:

```
from docx import Document
doc = Document("invitation.docx")
for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
    p = paragraph._element
    if '''(paraId == "1A403538")''':
        run_pr = p.xpath('./w:pPr/w:rPr')
        # append <vanish/>
```

Something I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

trees = minidom.parse("document.xml")
tagnames = trees.getElementsByTagName("w:rPr")

for tag in tagnames:
    child = ET.fromstring("<vanish/>")
    tag.appendChild(child)
```

I get the following error from line `tag.appendChild(child)`:

```
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'nodeType'
```

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You'll get better answers if you can first show us how you've tried to resolve this problem (for example, this  prevents people from suggesting things that it turns out you've already tried). There are a number of online resources that demonstrate how to parse and modify XML documents using Python; those may be a good place to start.

Comment: You're right. I've edited added some stuff I tried and what I'm actually looking for. Everything that I found about parsing and modifying XML documents doesn't actually match my case. I'm gonna look further and try to understand how to make it work. Just thought any insight I get from here could lead me in the right direction or maybe someone had the same problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.